# Como fazer uma notificação de aumento usando ajax + php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estou apenas tentando aumentar a notificação de um item. Quero que sempre que adicionar um novo item ao meu carrinho, tenha de ver o número de aumento de notificação do carrinho. no console javascript vejo que está funcionando bem mas na minha tela nada muda. alguem pode me ajudar a ver onde esta o problema por favor?

Esse é a parte HTML. eu estou usando o id="show_result" para mostrar o que rola na parte back-end com ajax.

```
 <li class="ml-4"><a href="#login" id="total_cart"  class=" text-danger " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SignUp"><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></span><span id="show_result"></span></a></li>
```

Esse é a parte javascript com ajax:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "API/READ/count_panier.php",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#show_result').html(data);  
            //console.log the response
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}, 1000); //10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds
// MAKING REGISTRATION
```

E aqui está a pagina que eu chamo para contar se há dados que foram adicionando no carrinho.PAGINA: count_panier.php

```
$count = $conn->prepare("SELECT  *FROM panier");
$count->execute();
$counter = $count->rowcount();
echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">'.$counter.'</span>';
```

Comment: Como vc diz que no console aparece corretamente, o problema está no seu HTML e/ou css e nesse caso não há dados suficientes na pergunta para verificar o problema. Também diria que não faz muito sentido a sua "api" retornar HTML. Deveria alterar o retorno para um JSON, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Atualizar um elemento no DOM com o HTML daquele da chamada ajax pode ser feito dessa forma

$('#show_result').html($('#show_result',data).html());

ou
$('#show_result').replaceWith($('#show_result',data));

Comment: tentei seguir seu exemplo mas o problema continua infelizmente